# Jest error : SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, create-react-app

```
export default class TestClass {
  static async fetchFile () {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(
        url.to.file
      );
      if (!res.ok)
        throw new Error(
          'Something went wrong when downloading the file .',
        );
      config = await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
await TestClass.fetchFile();
```

In the application as I import library everything works , but the problem arises when I run tests in JEST . The configuration is standard and the settings as they were entered CRA(Create React App ) .  So we run the tests with the standard configuration of JEEST made by CRA .

So
In browser it works
import TestClass from './TestClass ';

But when I run the test in JEST I get error

```
  await TestClass.fetchFile();
    ^^^^^

    SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

I can change approach with this and change body this to

```
export default class TestClass {
  static async fetchFile () {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(
        url.to.file
      );
      if (!res.ok)
        throw new Error(
          'Something went wrong when downloading the file .',
        );
      config = await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

And in index.js

import TestClass from './TestClass ';

```
(async () => {
  await TestClass.fetchFile();
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
})() 

in test;
import TestClass from "./TestClass ";
beforeAll(async () => {
  await TestClass.fetchFile();
});
```

I think it should work

I need do it before start
It is possible to configure JEST in such a way that this solution does not interrupt tests with an error

Comment: ....what's your question? And what is "IS"?

Comment: @JaredSmith
My question is how to solve the problem that occurs when I test the application in " JEST". No "IS" was supposed to be " JEST" already corrected.

Comment: Unless you have `type: module` in your `package.json` and your tests are modules (.mjs file extension), you will get that error just from importing the file with the top-level await. If you own that file, don't do that (importing a file shouldn't have side-effects anyway, that's bad practice). If you don't own that file, *consider carefully* whether you want a library that would do something like that as a dependency.  If you're stuck and you have to use it but can't change it, you could possibly mock it out entirely for your tests or make all your tests .mjs files.

Comment: ...additionally, modifying an external variable in an awaited fetch like that is a well-known anti-pattern, all of this looks like an attempt to turn an async result into a sync one, and that just isn't going to work. You can't make [red functions into blue ones](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/).

Comment: Hi @JaredSmith what do you mean ?
", modifying an external variable in an awaited fetch like that is a well-known anti-pattern"

Why do we need to download this file ? Because my Devops wants to have one image for multiple environments rally so through this file the configuration is passed. I have this definition of what this environment is , how to BE ... In the usual approach, I would put this information in .env.

Comment: @JaredSmith  ", modifying an external variable in an awaited fetch  " 

 What I do is I download the .json file  with the configuration and use a static class is to share this information in the app. Maybe this is the wrong approach but at this point I have no idea how else to dynamically transmit configurations .

Comment: "what do you mean" re: well known anti-pattern see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron). You shouldn't need to fetch a file to run unit tests, and if your devops says otherwise they're an idiot, try to break it to them gently. "In the usual approach, I would put this information in .env." yes exactly you should do that. I'm sorry if you can't. "I have no idea how else to dynamically transmit configuration" call the static method in your test file and make all your tests async, which jest can handle...

Comment: ...just fine. I would try really hard push back though on this though, you shouldn't have to fetch dynamic config to run **unit** tests. Sorry if it doesn't go your way.

Comment: Hey, you might try NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest